# Special character $ not read from command line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, special-characters, command-line-arguments, argparse

This is my code

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.echo
```

When I try to pass text with `$` from command line it is not taken. I tried to escape the special character by adding `\` before the `$` symbol but still no luck. This is how I'm running the code

`python test.py Sample$how 
Sample`

I'm on windows and I already tired escaping using `\` but didn't work out.

How can I make my code take `$` sign ?

Comment: try `python test.py 'Sample$how'`. So the $how does not get seen as a variable.

Comment: Thanks @vds, it resolves the issue.

Comment: @vds why do single quotes work, but not double quotes? I had tried to avoid shell expansion with the later, but didn't have any luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @vds comment to the question:

I bet you're using Powershell(?)

In Powershell, `$how` would be expanded to the value of the (probably non-existing) variable `how`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules

Python (or any other executable) would never even see the dollar sign.

Adding single quotes around the variable fixes the issue:

`python test.py 'Sample$how'`

Comment: Hey @steinar, test.py read 'Sample$how' including the single quotes and so I will have to manually remove the single quotes. How can this be rectified with out manual removal.

Answer (score 1):

These options work for me in bash:

```
$ python test.py 'Sample$how'
Sample$how
$ python test.py Sample\$how
Sample$how
$ python test.py "Sample\$how"
Sample$how
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm on windows and I tired but didn't work out